# Why can't enable_if be used on specialized parameter?

Tags: templates, c++11

I am trying to create a partial specialization for integral types. My idea was to do something similar to:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Class {
};

template <typename T>
struct Class<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type> {
};
```

This however leads to the following error:

```
error: template parameters not deducible in partial specialization:
struct Class<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type> {
       ^
note: 'T'
```

It does work if I use an extra template parameter:

```
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T, typename Enable = void>
struct Class {
};

template <typename T>
struct Class<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type> {
};
```

Why do I need the extra template parameter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the first case you are not specializing the class.
When you write:

```
template <typename T>
struct Class<typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value, T>::type> {
};
```

that T is still a generic template type, and your compiler gets confused.

In the second case, when you write

```
template <typename T>
struct Class<T, typename std::enable_if<std::is_integral<T>::value>::type> {
};
```

You correctly specialize the template parameter `Enable`, and everything works fine.

If you want to specialize the first one, you should do it type by type, which is probably not what you want

```
template <>
struct Class<std::enable_if<std::is_integral<int>::value, int>::type> {
};
```

Comment: But doesn't the specialization also resolve to Class<T, void>? I can't understand how this second case is clear to the compiler.

Comment: you don't actually need the `Enable = void`, leave it out and it should work fine as well. `template <typename T, typename Enable>` should do the trick

Comment: Ah! Now I see! The base case is Class<T, E>. The specialization is Class<T, void>, so template parameter E is now specialized. Without E the compiler would think that there is no partial specialization in action (the specialization has the same type as the base case). Thanks for shining a light on this one!